# No solutions to change brightness on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, ubuntu-16.04, brightness

I recently bought a new laptop (MSI GL62M 7RDX) and installed a Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot on it.

The thing is, there's no way I can't change the brightness on Ubuntu. I had the same problem on the Windows but a Intel driver solved the problem. But for Ubuntu, I didn't found any of that, I know there was an update tool but it seems that it doesn't exist anymore.

And oh boy I have tried everything : change .conf files, add some options in the grub config file, installed alternative brightness softwares. The GC driver is installed.

It seems that the Ubuntu doesn't recognize at all the Intel video graphics, my **/sys/class/backlight/** folder is empty

I just don't know what to try next, does someone has a magical fix for this ? Please save my eyes

Comment: You likely need an up-to-date driver for the Intel graphics.  Did you try a more recent version of Ubuntu (17.04 or 17.10, at least booting from USB/LiveCD), in case it includes and up-to-date driver?

Comment: I had the exact same problem with 17.10, installed from USB too. I thought maybe 16.04 LTS was a more stable version, but it didn't changed anything

Comment: your laptop also has NVIDIA graphics. Install a new proprietary driver NVIDIA. https://msi.com/Laptop/GL62M-7RDX/Specification